# Does cloudfront not support CORS with custom origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cloudfront

It seems like I can´t use a custom origin on [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) and a [cross-domain XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests) since CloudFront won´t forward the preflight OPTIONS request according to section *HTTP Methods* in [Request and Response Behavior, and Supported HTTP Status Codes for Custom Origins](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomHTTPMethods):

> CloudFront accepts only `GET` and `HEAD` requests from end users.

I can´t find anyone complaining about this on the web so can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Don't you only need the preflight for non get requests?

Comment: Yes but chrome will make an OPTIONS request before it makes the GET.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront now supports the following requests (including OPTIONS):

- DELETE
- GET
- HEAD
- OPTIONS
- PATCH
- POST
- PUT

The *HTTP Methods* section in [CloudFront documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomHTTPMethods) referenced in the question has been updated.

Comment: Finally. Thanks for finding this.

Comment: It still doesn't work with cache hits, only with cache misses.

Comment: @nikolay wouldn't it defeat the purpose of a CDN if it worked with cache hits?